# Link keyword in TextView to file/directory

Tags: android, file, directory, hyperlink, textview

Is there any way that I can link a keyword in a TextView to a file or directory on the user's SD card? My app produces stack trace files when it crashes and I want the user to able to click a link in my About dialog to view either the latest one or the folder containing all of them. (Something like "If this app crashes, please send [link]the latest stack.trace file[/link] to us at myapp@example.com.")

I know it is possible to use the following code to make a Web link but I tried to modify it to use "file:///sdcard/path/to/file/stack.trace" which causes my app to Force Close when the link is clicked.

```
<string name="strSample">This is Web link to &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;>Google&lt;/a>!</string>

final TextView tvSample = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSample);
tvSample.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String strSample = getResources().getString(R.string.strSample);
tvSample.setText(Html.fromHtml(strSample));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your method by replacing `Html.fromHtml(strSample)` part which returns `Spannable`. Create your own `Spannable` and add `ClickableSpan` to it. In the `onClick` method you can place whatever logic you need. Here's quick examle that you can extend

```
public Spannable getProfileLink(final Context context) {
    final String name = firstName + " " + lastName;
    Spannable spans = SpannableStringBuilder.valueOf(name);
    ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            // TODO - call profile here
            Toast.makeText(context, "Will call profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    };
    spans.setSpan(clickSpan, 0, name.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spans;
}
```